# Discontinuous Lévy-Processes with normal increments

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, levy-processes

Does there exist a Lévy-Process with normal increments but with paths that aren't even continuos when modified on null sets?

I'm asking because when defining Brownian motion as Lévy-Process, continuity is always required additionally. However, the only example of a noncontinuous "Brownian motion" I have encountered so far is where you take a continuous Brownian motion and set rational values (not rational points) to 0 (which I guess is modification on a null set?)

Comment: 1) you mean "almost surely discontinuous" in the first sentence?
2) path spaces and stochastic processes is always an interesting issue. Chapter 38 in Bauer's "Probability Theory" gives a good description, see http://books.google.de/books?id=w76IHsPHybcC&lpg=PA327&hl=de&pg=PA327#v=onepage&q&f=false
3) Normal increments via Kolmogorov-Centsov theorem allow a "continuous modification".

Comment: 1) no, I didn't, but I phrased it unclearly. I wanted to know if there exists a Levy-Process with normal increments that does not only have discontinous paths, but paths that aren't even modifiable on null sets to be continuous

Answer (score 1):

The conditions that a process $X$ is has independent increments and that these increments are normal uniquely determines the finite-dimensional distributions of the process, and so, in law, there exists only a single Levy process with normal increments, and that Levy process is the Brownian motion.

However, stochatic processes can exist relative to different sample spaces. The Kolmogorov extension theorem yields the existence of the Brownian motion on the space $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$ of mappings from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but not on the space $C[0,\infty)$ of conntinuous functions from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The process on  $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$ will not have continuous sample paths, but will have a version with continuous sample paths.

The assumption that the Levy process with normal increments also should have continuous sample paths can be seen as a statement that when we talk about this Levy process, we always take a version with continuous sample paths.

Comment: but the version on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$, do its discontinuous paths maybe have continuous representatives? I.e. can you modify the discontinuous paths on Lebesgue null sets of $[0,\infty)$ to obtain continuous paths?

Comment: Let $X$ have the distribution of a Brownian motion with paths in $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$. It can be shown that $P(X\in A)$, where $A$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$ defined by having $f\in A$ if and only if it holds for all $n\ge1$ that the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{Q}_+\cap[0,n]$ is uniformly continuous. All mappings $f$ in $A$ can be modified outside of $\mathbb{Q}_+$ to a continuous function. So yes, in this sense, the paths of $X$ are almost surely "almost continuous".

Comment: Thanks. And the process with modified paths, would it still be a Brownian motion?

Comment: Well, that depends on whether or not you require that a Brownian motion has continuous paths :-) But it would have the same distribution as a Brownian motion: Its finite-dimensional distributions would be the same, which suffices to determine the distribution.

Comment: I mean the formerly discontinuous-path process which we modified outside $\mathbb{Q}$ to have continous paths. Why does the answer then depend on if we require continuity? Also, is it obvious that the modified process still has the same distribution?

Comment: if you change each $X_t$ on a null set separately, then any $(X_{t_1},\ldots,X_{t_n})$ will be almost surely equal to their previous values, and thus in particular have the same distribution. In other words, if $P(X_t = Y_t)=1$ for all $t\ge0$, then $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

If the process with modified paths is the one with continuous paths, then it will have the same distribution. However, as far as I know, this also requires that the process is continuous in probability, so it's not entirely obvious.